# Autofill 2 form input from 1 autocomplete input to find code and price from a stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

> I have an autocomplete input that will automatically fill in the other
>   2 inputs, in this case I use json, my problem is when I type 2
>   characters in the fruit name input, it will bring up all the data in
>   the database, whereas it should only show data according to what which
>   I input, but if I use 'var json' which is on line 13, it will bring up
>   the data as I expected, and when I use source on line 16, it will
>   bring up all the data that I have, if there is an error in my code ? I
>   am very grateful if you can help me

```
<head>
  <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="secondInput" name="code" value="" placeholder="Code" readonly>
  <input type="text" id="field" name="fruit" value="" placeholder="Fruit name(input here)">
  <input type="text" id="thirdInput" name="price" value="" placeholder="Price" readonly="" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="12">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //var json = [{"code": "1","label": "Apple","price": "10000"},{"code": "17","label": "Banana","price": "20000"}];
        $("#field").autocomplete({
            //source: json,
      source: "<?= site_url('home/take_json_fruit'); ?>",
      data: { fruit: $("#field").val()},
      minLength: 2,
      dataType: "json",
      select: function(event, ui) {
       $("#secondInput").val(ui.item.code);
       $("#thirdInput").val(ui.item.price);
     },

     change: function (event, ui) {
       if (ui.item === null) {
        $(this).val('');
        $('#field_id').val('');
      }
    }
  });
        $("#field").focusout(function() {
            if ($("#field").val() === '') {
                $('#field_id').val('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> this is my function in controller className Home

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('Json_decode');
  }
  public function take_json_fruit()
  {
    $fruit = $this->input->post('fruit');
    $rows = $this->Json_decode->take_fruit_json($fruit);
    echo json_encode($rows);
  }
}
```

> and this is my model className Json_decode

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Json_decode extends CI_Model {
  public function take_fruit_json($fruit)
  {
    $this->db->select('code_fruit as code, fruit as label, price_fruit as price');
    $this->db->like('fruit', $fruit);
    $query = $this->db->get('fruits');
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not passing any data (selected/entered text) to the php to filter.

Comment: I updated my code, I've done it before, but it still shows up all the data from my database

Comment: Now you are sending the data but what is your php doing with it? don't you have to write a query that selects from database, filters by the data sent by autocomplete and then return only the records that matched. Where is your php code to filter by data?

Comment: thanks for keep helping me, i update my code again, at below the code i have controller and model in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This has been solved, I made a helper_codeigniter to extract data from
>   a table and make it variable in javascript, hope can help everyone

Answer (score 0):

The like in codeigniter's query builder class places the % both before and after the term. That is why you are getting (apparently) many extra results. 
Try the third optional parameter for like:

```
$this->db->like('fruit', $fruit, 'after');
```

[based on CI Documentation on Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: thank you but it's still doesn't work, because when i typing 2 or more just any character, it's keeping appear all data, i think something wrong with my js, because the js like doesn't catching my input correctly

Comment: So writing one letter works? but multiple letters does not work?

Comment: writing one character also doesn't work too, my setting is two input character because after I input 2 character it will appear my data based from the filter, for example: i typing 'ba' or 'na', it will appear 'banana', but the problem is when i typing 'ba' or 'na', it will appearing all data like 'banana', 'mango', 'watermelon', 'etc'. i think something wrong with the js, but i don't know whers wrong. actually i want to make like this example, http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/379/, but the difference is i want to using data from my db